# not able to get the data from html form to php script

Tags: php, html

I am having this code in my index.html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Admin Panel</h2>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "login.php">

<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" name="username">
<INPUT TYPE = "PASSWORD" name="password">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" NAME = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">

</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

and this code in my login.php file

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Login</title> 
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$adminUsername = "dushyant30suthar";

$adminPassword = "12345";

$enteredUsername = $_POST['username'];

$enteredPassword = $_POST['password'];
print ($enteredPassword);

if($enteredUsername == $adminUsername && $enteredPassword == $adminPassword)
  {
   print("Logged in");
   print ($username);
  }
else
  {
  print("Login Failed");
  print ($enteredUsername);
  print ($enteredPassword);
  print ($adminUsername);
  print ($adminPassword);
   }


 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

when I am trying to print the value i have got from index.html it is not showing any data but the values i have fixed in login.php are being shown.

Comment: @Pupil better give me the answer

Comment: use simple letters when coding

Comment: Have you tried putting `print_r($_REQUEST)` at the top of the Login.php page?

Comment: can you see anything in login.php?

Comment: have you tried to check if your button submit was clicked by using the built in function of php which is isset()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Admin Panel</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code for the `login.php` file and it's working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Login</title> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
$adminUsername = "dushyant30suthar";

$adminPassword = "12345";


if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
  $enteredUsername = $_POST['username'];

  $enteredPassword = $_POST['password'];

  print ($enteredPassword);

  if($enteredUsername == $adminUsername && $enteredPassword == $adminPassword)
    {
     print("Logged in");
     print ($enteredUsername);
    }
  else
    {
    print("Login Failed");
    print ($enteredUsername);
    print ($enteredPassword);
    print ($adminUsername);
    print ($adminPassword);
     }
}


 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added a check if has been submitted the form which is necessary:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
```

And fixed: `$username` is not defined, I changed it with `$enteredUsername`.

Comment: so what did you change on here?? mention that too

Comment: Tried but not solving the problem isset is false all time

Comment: Submit the form with filled inputs in  index.html and it will redirect you to login.php with `$_POST` values and the isset will not be false. The code has been tried and if it is working.

Comment: Please create two files with the code above then open the `index.html` file in the browser enter values for the fields and submit the form. Then you will see opening the login.php file with printing the values.

Comment: I am not getting sorry

Comment: Also there might not been happening anything if you are just opening the file `index.html` in the browser (dragging it into the browser). You should open it through a server - Apache for example. In order for the php code to work.

Comment: Brother I am doing it on server itself if it would not be a server then this code might not be working even a bit of it. (Live server)

Comment: I've changed the code for the two files. Please copy it for the both files again, refresh home.html, enter values in the fields and submit the form. It should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the login is working properly from what i'm testing, but you still have an error into `login.php`:

```
if($enteredUsername == $adminUsername && $enteredPassword == $adminPassword)
  {
   print("Logged in");
   print ($username);
  }
```

In the code you showed us `$username` isn't defined, you might want to change it to :

```
if($enteredUsername == $adminUsername && $enteredPassword == $adminPassword)
  {
   print("Logged in");
   print ($enteredUsername);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah i was my mistake but it is not showing any kind of change by removing that variable. My intention behind wrting that variable was to lets know is there any data in that variable and yeah There is no data in these variables